# What are the security risks by matching cell phone# for mobile app authentication?

Tags: react-native

My react native mobile app connects to my backend web server as below:

```
class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://myapp.com/smart-phone'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The phone# for a user has already been stored on backend web server. When the mobile app on the device is sending https connection request to the web server, the web server retrieves the device's phone# and compare it with the record it has stored. If the phone# matches that in the record, then sign in the device automatically. Otherwise reject the connection. What are the security risks for the authentication method above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast way of authentication, I can't see the possible risks with that but most of the messaging applications, like WhatsApp, use similar authentication methods but they also require a SMS validation. I think SMS validation provides two advantages:

1. You will validate that phone number is still active
2. and user really owns the phone number and have access to SMS

But also many operators don't put phone number information into SIM cards, so devices can't pick the phone number, also there are some methods that enables altering phone number information registered to SIM/device.

Comment: I am trying to get away from the the SMS verification. But no phone# from SIM cards may pose a real problem. Is there a way the SMS sent for initial login and after that login the device automatically? My app does not care much if the device is still active or who has it now.